# Stubbing Sinatra helper in Cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, sinatra, ruby-mocha

I am currently struggling with stubbing out a helper method of my **Sinatra** app from within **Cucumber**.

I have a **Sinatra** app with simple session authentication (by cookies) and I want to turn of authentication by stubbing out the `logged_in?` helper method for my **Cucumber** scenarios.
There seems to be a problem with Sinatra and Cucumber concerning sessions so I thought about just using Mocha to work around the problem.

However I don't know how I can access the `Sinatra::Application` instance from within a `Given`-Block to stub out the method.

Comment: Being completely unfamiliar with any of these, I simply congratulate you on your question title.

Comment: should I change the title to avoid the not-intended pun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the right context by using `Sinatra::Application.class_eval`

Edit: See original poster's answer for full explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood my question. The logged_in? method already works within the sinatra app, but I want to stub it out for integration testing (no authentication to test certain workflows). The main problem is that I don't know how to access the instance of my application from within Cucumber steps.

Comment: I see.  I think I understand now.  Maybe something with Sinatra::Application.class_eval { }

Comment: yup, this made it work. Thanks, how can I give you props for that hint? I'll answer my own question to clarify what I've done.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  My answer is not complete.  You could just upvote it and mark yours as correct.  That seems like the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like I need to directly override my Authentication mechanism within a `Before do ... end`-block

So I ended up with a `hooks.rb` placed in `features/support/` file overwriting my `logged_in?` and the `current_user` method.

```
Before do
  MySinatraApplicationClass.class_eval do
    helpers do
      def logged_in?
        return true
      end
      def current_user
        # This returns a certain Username usually stored 
        # in the session, returning it like
        # that prohibits different user logins, but for
        # now this is enough for me
        "Walter"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The only thing I had to take care of, is that the no other actions within the application directly read from `session` but rather use those helpers.

Sadly I think this way of handling session based Sinatra applications through Cucumber is already described somewhere else and I just thought *my problem was different*.